# How to launch My app Activity from account icon in contacts

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have an Account Authenticator and Sync Adapter which stored the my app contacts separately into my account. That account icon is also getting displayed for those contacts. But am not getting how to go into an activity once i click the account icon of a particular user.

For eg. If we click the whatsapp icon in our contacts, it leads us to the whatsapp's chat page of that particular user. Like the same way, i need to call an intent that leads to an Activity.

I tried following code:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.ChatRoomActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.my.ex.contacts" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    ContentValues mValues;
    mValues.put(TransferUpSyncAdapterColumns.DATA_PID, contact.getServerContactId());
    mValues.put(Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.my.ex.contacts");
    mValues.put(TransferUpSyncAdapterColumns.DATA_SUMMARY, "my Contacts"
    mValues.put(TransferUpSyncAdapterColumns.DATA_DETAIL, "my profile");
```

then added the RawContact using batch operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the account type for the launcher activity in your manifest file

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="YOUR Custom mimeType" />
        </intent-filter>
```